# Front-end rendering issues on Linux

Tags: front-end, linux

I'm using Mathematica 12.2 on Ubuntu Mate 20.10 on an AMD FX(tm)-8120 with a GeForce GTX 1070 Ti NVIDA card.

The issue is that I get unwanted horizontal lines just below the cell that I'm working on which sometimes interfere with what I'm doing.
[image]

I have started Mathematica with and without the -mesa flag with no change.

This doesn't happen with standard Ubuntu. Below is a shortlist of installs that have worked and ones that gave me the issue:

**Kubuntu (20.04)**: Mathematica issues with unwanted horizontal lines

**Gnome desktop installed on my Kubuntu**: Mathematica worked but I had all kinds of other KDE/Gnome issues

**Ubuntu Mate(20.10)**: Mathematica issues with unwanted horizontal lines

I would really like to stay with Ubuntu Mate but I have to solve the Mathematica issue.

I'm looking for any ideas to try. If all else fails I'll have to go back to Ubuntu, I just really do not like Gnome 3.*

Comment: Do the line move when you scroll? I've never seen that with Linux Mint.

Comment: They stay in the same relative location when scrolling but move to below the active cell.

Comment: @anderstood which desktop do you use with Mint?

Comment: The default, cinnamon

Comment: @anderstood I switched to Linux Mint with Cinnamon. Works like a charm!

Comment: Great! I was sorry that nobody could help.